# Convert Image from Buffer to display in Frontend (Flutter)

Tags: database, mongodb, flutter, buffer, flutter-image

I have a backend based on NodeJS and using mongodb as the database. Images with the field name photo is saved as object Type Buffer. I have successfully sent Images from the app using form data but I am not able to display the image in frontend.

This is the function used to get the data from API

```
Future<User> userWithId() async {
  User result;
   try {
      final response = await http.get(
        'api link',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        result = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      }
   } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
   }
  return result;
}
```

This is the fromJson function of the class User. The photo field here returns the image as buffer.

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return User(
    id: json['_id'] as String ?? "",
    email: json['email'] as String ?? "",
    // profilePhoto: json["photo"] ?? null,
    // profilePhoto: base64.encode(jsonDecode(json["photo"])) ?? null,
  );
}
```

This is the data from the photo field
[image]

This is the data from MongoDB database
[image]

Comment: @Android_id How do I get the 'img string from json'?

Comment: Can you plz share your json

Comment: @Android_id I cannot print the json as it is too large. You can see image from the mongo db compass. ````json['photo']['data']['data']```` returns the list of integers

Comment: ```` type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' ```` This error shows up

Comment: @Android_id its an array

Comment: ````Base64Decoder().convert(compressed)```` shows this error ````The argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'````

Comment: use List<dynamic> in place of List<int> and List<String>

Comment: @Android_id, where are you getting ````uint8list````.

Comment: @ShriyaPandya, not clear with what you said. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I would like to ask what is the return type of "profilePhoto" in you model class?  can you paste complete model class here?

Comment: hi Nehal, Did you get a solution for this

Comment: No solution yet

Answer (score 1):

For those who are facing this issue as well, this is a multi-part problem:

1. Converting List to List.
2. Using converted List to read/display image.

In OP's case, to get buffer List would be `profilePhoto: json["photo"]["data"]["data"]`.

For step 1, To convert List to List:

```
List<dynamic> bufferDynamic = profilePhoto: json["photo"]["data"]["data"];
List<int> bufferInt = buffer.map((e) => e as int).toList();
```

For step 2 as some have already mention, use [Image.memory class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) provided by Flutter.

```
Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(bufferInt))
```

Hope this helps for those who need to read/display image from buffer. (:

Comment: You sir are incredible, NO answer on the internet was the solution, only yours. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `base64Decode` method from `dart:convert`

store your image binary in string format:

```dart
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return User(
    ...
    profilePhoto: json["photo"] ?? null,
    ...
  );
}
```

and use the following code in UI:

```dart
Image.memory(base64Decode(user.profilePhoto))
```

also, don't forget to add an if statement to check if the photo is null or not

Hope, it helps

Comment: ````type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'````
This error shows up when using ````json["photo"]````
While using  ````json["photo"]['data']['data']```` this error shows up ````type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'````

Answer (score 0):

json['photo']['data']['data'];
By doing this you are getting this error List' is not a subtype of type 'String'. So may be your return type for profilePhoto is String. Change it to dynamic then try again.

Comment: Can you provide related codes to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great article bellow explaining about bytes in dart, you can convert your response data which is as List of integers, to **Uint8List** data type and pass it to **Image.memory** to render image.

```
Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(// pass image data array here));
```

https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-bytes-in-dart-6ece83455721

Comment: I am facting problem to get the List of Integeres

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
List<int> imageData = user.profilePhoto['data'] as List<int>
////
Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(imageData));
```

Comment: I try that but ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5275:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5143:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:1999:60)

Answer (score 0):

#### Image type

You should modify your class User, currently you have something like:

```dart
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final ? profilePhoto
}
```

I am not sure which type you are currently using but you need to change it accordingly to the data you get in your response. Your image is, in your computer, a list of bytes (uint8, meaning unsigned integer of 8 bits, so 1 byte), ranging from 0 to 255 in value (0 to 0xFF).

---

#### Images header

You can read about [EXIF](https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html) to understand better how the standard specifies the formats for images

> Every JPEG file starts from binary value '0xFFD8', ends by binary value '0xFFD9'.

> The first eight bytes of a [PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) file always contain the following (decimal) values: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10

---

#### Fix

Change the type of your `profilePhoto` to `Uint8List`, full code:

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  String profilePhoto // I don't know which type you use

  User({this.id, this.email, this.profilePhoto});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      id: json['_id'] as String ?? "",
      email: json['email'] as String ?? "",
      profilePhoto: json["photo"] ?? null,
    );
  }
}
```

And then load the image in your widget with [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) while being cautious as its value could be `null`:

```dart
return user.profilePhoto != null ? Image.memory(user.profilePhoto) : Container();
```

NB: Image.memory is a shorthand of an Image widget backed by [MemoryImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html).